# Scala Casbah - Converting a command-line String filter to DSL filter

Tags: mongodb, scala

I have an application which streams mongo documents and I would like to add a feature which allows the end user to define custom filters for the outgoing documents.  The application is written in Scala and uses the Casbah driver.  Essentially I would like to pass through the entire filter string (IE, "pop" $gt 1000) and convert it to a type that collection.find() can accept.

Basically, I'm looking for something like this:

```
val filter = """pop" $gt 1000""" //This is passed in from the command-line
val cast = ??? (need to convert the string filter into a DSL Object)
collection.find(cast)  //cast should have the value "pop" $gt 1000
```

I've been poking around online and in the Casbah docs but I can't find a simple way to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there is no way to do that in Casbah, you'd have to write your own parser.

The nearest I can think of is to use [Jongo](http://jongo.org/) to parse mongo shell like documents and convert them into `DBObjects`.

Alternatively, scala 2.11 did add JSR-223 Scripting Engine support and you do an evil eval:

```
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager

val e = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("scala")
e.eval(""""pop" $gt 1000""")
```

If you are resorting to eval then make sure you are solving the issue in the correct way ;) And all the usual caveats apply - don't trust input from unknown sources.

Comment: Thanks.  I ended up using the jackson JSONParser and ObjectMapper.  I take the json string and read it into a HashMap using the ObjectMapper.  Once I've got the hash map I can load it into a MongoDBObject and at that point I have my filter object.